# Pass dictionary data to another view

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

How to pass the dictionary to another view of another app?

I have a view 1 of app_1 :

```
def index(request):

    if request.method=='POST':
        formConnex =ConnexionForm(request.POST)
        if formConnex.is_valid():

            nom_utilisateur = formConnex.cleaned_data['nom_utilisateur']    
            dicInfoCon =    {
                'utilisateur_key':nom_utilisateur,

            }

                return redirect('/app_1/', {'user_key':nom_utilisateur})
```

In view 2 of app_2:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'app_2/index.html')
```

Comment: I'm not sure why would you need that, but view is an independent point of entry and you can't share a variable with it. But if you describe your intentions maybe we can help to have a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to share variables between two views there are several approaches
For instance, you can set that variable in session and retrieve it in second view

```
request.session['some_key'] = dicInfoCon
```

And in you second view, you read that value from session

```
dicInfoCon = request.session.get("some_key")
```